# PyDrake - DirectCollocation - input_port(5) (applied spatial force) is KAbstractValued. How can I turn it to kVectorValued?

Tags: drake

I'm attempted to run DirectCollocation on a free body but am running into a Vector Type issue. My plant consists of just the ground and the body (from a urdf) and I want to use the DirectCollocation(plant, context....) object in order to find it's ideal initial state for it to land in some orientation based on a set of constraints. This is the error that I'm getting.

[Picture of Error Message for kVectorValued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orgxL.png)

This is the diagram that I'm working with.

[First half of diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lpKV.png)
[Second half of diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShxRz.png)

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DirectCollocation` (or many other planning and control methods in Drake) with `MultibodyPlant`, you will likely need to pass `plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index()` into `input_port_selection`.